# Making an image stay within a div in the same location

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my site currently:

I want to make the bouncing arrow stay in that exact same location depending on the viewers computer size screen but I cannot figure it out. I tried many things like styling the position but still ends up out of the div.

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="home">
  <h1>HELLO!<h1 style="font-family: ProximaNovaSemibold;">MY NAME IS</h1></h1>
  <br>
  <a class="smoothScroll" href="#work"> <img id="angleDown" style="margin-top:15%;" width="60px" height="60px" alt="" src="img/angle-down.png" /></a>
</div>
```

This is the style I am using for the div

```
 #home {
   background: url('img/img-home.jpg') no-repeat center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100vh;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 13.4%;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: try `position: fixed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.smoothScroll{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Thus always be at the bottom of the image, is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is the `position: fixed` CSS-property.

First I would take your anchor-scroll-element and put it at the end of your html:

```
  <a class="smoothScroll" href="#work"> <img id="angleDown" width="60px" height="60px" alt="" src="img/angle-down.png" /></a>

</body>
```

Then in your CSS-file, something like this:

```
.smoothScroll {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
}

#angleDown {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

And best look into these articles:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/